# How to connect to Android device from windows pc for internet

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, bluetooth, desktop

I have enabled Bluetooth tethering in Android phone. From windows, i need to connect to Android for internet

How to do via api or windows command?

Uwp app/ win32 api

Comment: BluetoothSetService for DUN service.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, can u refer me some doc on this?

Comment: Will this function BluetoothSetServiceState connects to Bluetooth pan network? Or it justs enables the service for Android device as per doc?

Comment: It installs drivers and connects to device from PC side. Of course, device must be paired before.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothsetservicestate